# HTML Responsive Email: 3 column layout for desktop/tablet to 2 column layout for phone

Tags: html, responsive-design, html-table, media-queries, html-email

Trying to create a responsive HTML email that has a 3 column (multiple rows) layout for desktop/tablet and changes to 2 columns (multiple rows) for phone display using tables(`<table>` `<tr>` `<td>`). I've only found solutions online that go from a large device multi-column layout to a single column small device layout using mainly tables. What is the best strategy on how to code this type of layout? I've tried referencing resources mainly from Mailchimp, Campaign Monitor and Litmus.

The code below goes from 3 columns (large display) to 1 column (phone display)

Link to code: https://github.com/alexwang949/html-responsive-email/blob/master/tables.html

Comment: Give Twitter Bootstrap a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach you'd likely need to take is what's becoming known as the "hybrid" email build.

The basic idea is to build for mobile first, as Android's increasingly popular Gmail client does not support the style tag (and thus media queries) at all. Then, use widely-supported modern CSS to build the columns for webmail clients, Thunderbird and Apple clients. Finally, use Outlook-specific comments to create "ghost columns" (for example) to whip Outlook clients into shape. *Note: this step only works if your email provider doesn't strip out comments on send.*

It's a time-consuming process requiring some strategy, but ultimately this layered approach will yield results, which is the name of the email game.

There's a fantastic article about this here:
http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-future-proof-responsive-email-without-media-queries--cms-23919

Comment: Thank you St.G for explaining your strategy. What are your thoughts on using email frameworks like Zurb?

Comment: Zurb is largely a manifestation of all of these techniques. I haven't used it myself (our shop requires flexibility not found here) but it looks like something worthwhile if you are keen to using frameworks. Personally, I prefer to master the concepts that make frameworks like this possible.

Comment: Update on Zurb: this is widely considered to be dead. HTML email environments change rapidly, so unless frameworks like this are *very* actively maintained, they quickly gain issues and become unusable. Having said that, there are newer ones that are maintained like MJML or Maizzle, but I think what's even better is just having your own components that you can copy and paste (and update yourself without having to wait for a dev or setup a complex system).