# Email HTML nav with left and right elements including logo, button and text

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, html-email

For some reason, no matter what I do, this fails. Is there a ready solution somewhere?
My code is a mess now because I tried too many things.

Setting widths didn't work on mobile. It made the text squish vertically, even after adjusting font size in responsive as well as the logo size.

It's the way the cells are set up that doesn't let this happen. I have it in 3 columns right now. Should I do 2 columns, with the right hand side built with a nested table?

Thanks!
See images for desired design and the various flops-
[image: nav design]

[image: Vertical Flop]

[image: All the way to the left]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML Responsive Email: 3 column layout for desktop/tablet to 2 column layout for phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34071512/html-responsive-email-3-column-layout-for-desktop-tablet-to-2-column-layout-for)

Comment: Hey Pitzki, it would be really helpful if you could post your current code so we can see where you're going wrong.

Comment: @Digital_Frankenstein thanks. I posted an answer with code.

Answer (score 0):

I would use   display: flex; and justify-content: space-between;
So, for this nav bar that you have, surround it with a class, example class="top"
Then in your styles sheet I would do:

```
.top {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

If you want that bar to show up at all times then I would add this line to the css, position:fixed;

Your html should look something like

```
<nav class='top'>
   <div class='logo'></div>
   <div>
      <p>Tuesday, January 1st 2021</p>
   </div>
   <button>
      <a href"">Contact US</a>
   </button>
</nav>
```

Comment: This is for email, not web. Will it work?

Comment: @pitzki if it is still html i don't see why it wouldn't work , i am not very familiar with the difference that it would have

Comment: If you haven't developed HTML for email before then it's a bit hard to explain, but in short, nothing ever ever works as it should and any CSS and HTML technology after 1999 is considered too new (a bit exaggerating but that's the idea), and has no support.

Comment: `Display: flex` actually has decent support across emails, but, notably nothing for Outlook desktops. Divs are also problematic for the same reason. https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-display-flex/

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of clarity I removed all the excess code such as styling and modifiers.

This worked. I used a 2-col table at 100%. Each col was not given any width. The right-hand col had a nested table with 2 cells, again, no widths at all. That cell was right aligned.

```
<table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <!--Column 1 of 2 for Logo, no width is defined-->
                                                            <td align="left" >
                                                               
                                                                <table align="left">
                                                                    <tr> 
                                                                        <td> 
                                                                            <div id="logo-top">       
                                                                                <a> <img src="" height="auto" style="width:100%;height:auto;max-width:120px;" width="120" id="logotop"></a>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </table>

                                                            </td>
                                                            
                                                            <!--Column 2 of 2 for date and button-->
                                                            <td>
                                                                <!--Nested a 2 column table inside, the table is aligned to the right, no width is defined-->    
                                                                <table border="0" align="right" > 
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td align="right">
                                                                            <div style="margin-right: 20px /*margin between date and button*/" >
                                                                                <a style="color: #000000 /* inline styling as link because dates get detected + I used the longest date possible to test for space*/ "> September 24, 2021</a>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </td>
                                                            
                                                                        <td style="the style I needed" bgcolor="#00b7b4" >
                                                                            <div><a style="color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none;"> Contact Us</a>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                        </td> 

                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </table>
                                                            </td>
                                                            
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Going by your second sentence... Is this fixed now?

Comment: Yes. For mobile though, I had used media queries to make everything smaller.

Comment: Awesome! Oh, so desktop is still an issue?

Comment: Oh sorry if I wasn't clear, I fixed it everywhere, and noted that to adjust for mobile I needed media queries or else they all break into 2 lines.