# Collapse email columns on mobile view without code duplication

Tags: css, mobile, html-email, email-templates

The goal is to have 2 diferrent email layouts - one for mobile and one for desktop. The desktop version has 2 columns and in the mobile version the content should collapse to only 1 column (like in pictures below [desktop view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0KL4.png), [mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dv7qd.png)). It’s important that if the blocks are different heights the border on the left is the same height for both of them.
It’s also important to have as little code duplication between the mobile and desktop views as possible otherwise the email size would be too large.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share some code in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML Responsive Email: 3 column layout for desktop/tablet to 2 column layout for phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34071512/html-responsive-email-3-column-layout-for-desktop-tablet-to-2-column-layout-for)

Comment: In that question, it doesn't address the border heights, but for that, due to the way this is achieved in email, it's only possible manually (that is, add padding to make it match). This is because each column is separate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox.

set `min-width` to the cards and set `display: flex` to parent contained. and set `flex-wrap: wrap`

Example:
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/vakhariaheet/pen/RwaoJRz)

PS: Ignore JS Part in the Codepen

Comment: `display: flex` does not have [full e-mail support](https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-display-flex/) yet, unfortunately.